# GIT: Pinpoint a change in a file

Tags: git

I have in the 'master' branch of a repo a file, myFile.txt, with some content. A developer, developerA, created a branch and did some stuff in it and among that stuff he altered the myFile.txt. While developerA were working the developerB did some changes in that same myFile.txt.

Both of 'em pushed to the central repo so our CI system could build the component. The developerA pushed, then the developerB pushed. For whatever odd reason the developerA changes can be seen in the file history 'git whatchanged myFile.txt' and the developerB isn't shown.

when i clone the repo, the HEAD of my 'master' branch checkout the changes of developerB but querying the history i can't pinpoint the commit that changed the content of the file made by developerB.

How that happened? How can i locate the commit that changed the content of the file?

Comment: Have you tried `git log myFile.txt` and `git blame myFile.txt`?

Comment: I've tryed it, but only the first commit showed up... I'm still trying to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be, that the commits of **developerA** and **developerB** are on different branches.

The easiest way to solve your problem should be to use the [`--all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) flag of `git log`.